# Cloud Shell Technical Bug - Has anyone else experienced this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I use two DELL U2718Q monitors. One of them is placed horizontal and the other is vertical. When I open Cloud Shell in horizontal and let's say start deploying my app on App Engine. File uploading and service update will take some time and while on this position I move my browser from horizontal display to vertical, Cloud Shell goes crazy. Loading line starts moving down and everything moves to random position. This happens to me every time and it is pretty annoying. Below is a picture of what happens after App Engine loading finishes.

This is just the part that does not contain sensitive information

[image: This is just the part that does not contain sensitive information]

Has anyone experienced something like this?
If yes please let me know what is the issue.

**EDIT**
I have created an issue in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174514377). Please vote so that they could fix it faster.

Comment: If you are reducing the screen space of the "window" to Cloud Shell, this is expected. This will happen with `vi`, `ssh` and many other tools. These programs read the row and column numbers at program start only, not during execution. In your example, I am guessing you reduced the column width going to the vertical monitor.

Comment: So, the only solution is not to change the window size during the execution? Most of the time I do it unintentionally while doing my work. I was hoping there would be some way to handle this.

Comment: Because the display in in your browser, changing the browser is not reflected back to the SSH session. I see no easy way to support resizing. SSH and HTML do not communicate with each other. There are good security reasons to never allow that.